# Least residue power modulo

Tags: modular-arithmetic

May someone confirm that the least residue of $44^8$ modulo $7$ is $4$ please?

And that $2^2 \equiv  4\, (\!\!\!\mod 7)$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $44^6\equiv1\pmod7$ by Fermat's little theorem, so $44^8\equiv44^2\equiv2^2\equiv4\pmod7$

Answer (score 2):

It is correct: $44\equiv 2\mod 7$, so  $44^8\equiv 2^8\mod 7$. Now $2^3\equiv 1\mod 7$, so $2^8\equiv 2^{8\bmod 3}=2^2\mod 7=4$, since $0\le 4<7$.

Comment: Thanks for your help However may you kindly explain the part "2^2 = 1 mod 7" please

Comment: Which part should be explained?

Comment: The part 2^2 = 1 mod 7

Comment: Oh! Sorry, it was a typo, and I forgot to check before posting. I meant $2^3$ (which explains the $2^{8\bmod 3}$). It's fixed now.

Comment: Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

Lemma needed : For $a,b,n,r \in \mathbb{Z^+},$

$$a \equiv b \pmod{n} \implies a^r \equiv b^r \pmod{n}.$$

Proof:

$\displaystyle a\equiv b \pmod{n} \implies n | (a - b) \implies$

$\displaystyle \exists ~k \in \mathbb{Z} ~\text{such that}~ a = (b + nk) \implies$

$\displaystyle (a^r - b^r) = (b + nk)^r - b^r$

[Using binomial expansion]
$\displaystyle =~ \sum_{i=0}^r \left[(b)^i (nk)^{r - i}\right]
~-~ b^r$

$\displaystyle =~ \sum_{i=0}^{(r-1)} \left[(b)^i (nk)^{r - i}\right].$

Since the above summation stops at $(r-1)$,
$n$ divides each term in the summation.

Therefore
$n | (a^r - b^r) \implies a^r \equiv b^r \pmod{n}.$